# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to set all elements with a specific class to have a certain background-color.

Here is my code:

```
/*var elements = $(".km-flat");
    var elements1 = $(".km-view");
    var elements2 = $(".km-navbar");
    var elements3 = $(".km-content");
    elements.style.background-color = "red";
    elements1.style.background-color = "red";
    elements2.style.background-color = "red";
    elements3.style.background-color = "red";*/

    var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".km-content");

    for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
        myElements[i].style.background-color = "red";
    }
```

As you can see my first attempt was no good and is commented out. My second attempt is saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment javascript`.

What syntax should I be using? Thanks.

Comment: Invalid property: `.background-color`. You need to camelCase it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `-`, say like bellow

```
myElements[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

OR

```
myElements[i].style["background-color"] = "red";
```

**NOTE:-** If you will go through the comments bellow, you'll get to know the second way gives some problem in FF.

Comment: Dude, jst few seconds before you have posted..Anyways just chill :-)

Comment: @cookiemonster As for as I know it should be, if you know any problem regarding that let me know.

Comment: Are you saying the jsFiddle demo I posted changed the color? It doesn't for me in Firefox.

Comment: @cookiemonster ya I get that in firefox it's not workig, but what is the reason, I don't know should I remove the OR part.

Comment: Not sure  how the spec defines it, but if it doesn't work in a major browser, it's probably not a feasible solution for most people. You may want to put a note on there that it doesn't work in FF.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that works:

```
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".km-content");

for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
    myElements[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```